# How do I give a specific amount of items based on a scoreboard's score?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a datapack, and I want to make convertible scores on it. What I mean when I say "convertible" is that I want it to give you a specific amount of items based on the scoreboard's score.

Comment: Ummm... That post is missing some text!

Comment: Oh! Sorry, didn't notice. I'll add that now.

Comment: I think you might be able to use `/loot` for this. But getting something that drops your desired number of items is tricky, because I'm pretty sure that that feature is broken for containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no instant way of doing this but you can run a /give command, decrease the score by 1 and repeat until the score reaches 0.

So it would go like this:

```
/execute as @a[scores={someScore=1..}] run give @s ...
/scoreboard players remove @a[scores={someScore=1..}] someScore 1
```

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but it looks like this is the only way. Thank you :)